# Smooth UI while parsing JSON

Tags: android, json, performance, parsing

I have a app which parses some big JSON files.

The parsing is done in it's own thread with the lowest priority. However, while I'm parsing the UI becomes almost completely unresponsive.

I'm using Gson for the parsing and I know Jackson might give me better results. However - I still don't understand why the UI should become laggy when I do work in another thread.

Maybe I'm running out of memory? I'm not sure - is there a way I can see that?

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        final JSONArray finalResponse = response;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                feedParser.feedParser(finalResponse);
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

inside feedParser(finalResponse) 99% of the time is used just parsing the response like this:

```
SubscriptionWrapper[] subscriptionWrappers = gson.fromJson(
            jsonArray.toString(), SubscriptionWrapper[].class);
```

EDIT2: Just rewrote so using AsynvTask instead. It performs somewhat better but still very laggy.

```
private static class VolleyResultParser extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, Void, Void> {

    FeedParserWrapper feedParser = null;

    public VolleyResultParser(FeedParserWrapper feedParser) {
        this.feedParser = feedParser;
    }
     protected Void doInBackground(JSONArray... response) {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            feedParser.feedParser(response[0]);
            return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why you are not performing parsing via for example AsyncTask and showing some dialog during parsing?

Comment: post some code. you should be using asynctask as @Sajmon suggested

Comment: I'm actually not using AsyncTask for this because it's sch a short piece of code. Is that really a problem?

Comment: You don't have to define a new Thread in `doInBackground()`. The code from doInBackgroud() automatically is run in another thread. Just call `feedParser()` in doInBackground()

Comment: @AndyRes I don't define a new Thread in doInBackground(). I'm just setting the priority of the current background thread to a minimum

Comment: My bad, didn't notice.